# Disable checkboxes that will appear empty when filtering

Tags: checkbox, filter, filtering

**Link to the filter:**
`code:` http://jsfiddle.net/ar3PY/92/

**Question:**
I can filter and I will get result "empty"
But how to disable checkboxes that will anyway appear empty when filtering.
!!Notice that each category shall no filter with itself, only with other categories.

**For example**:
If I check "VOLVO" and "SILVER" I get "empty".
**What I looking for:**
If I check "VOLVO", then "SILVER" will be disabled.

**Image that show how it should work**:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just needed to access your class attributes to make it work. I forked your fiddle, here's the modified version:

```
   $("#filters :checkbox").click(function() { 
        var subj = this;
        resetBoxes();
        $(".filterme").show();

    if(this.checked){
      var all = $(".filterme");
      var tgts = all.filter(getFilter("brand")).filter(getFilter("class")).filter(getFilter("color"));
      var brandtgt = tgts[0].className.split(' ')[1];
      $("#filters :checkbox").each(function(idx){
        var inval = $(this).attr("value");
        var brandclasses = tgts[0].className.split(' ');
        var found = $.inArray(inval, brandclasses);

        if(found<0){
            disable($(this));
        }

        });
    all.not(tgts).hide();
    tgts.show();
    if (tgts.length == 0) {
        $('.empty').show();
    } else {
        $('.empty').hide();
    }
}
});
```

I've included helper functions (`resetBoxes, enable, disable`) found in the working fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ppzwmvs9/6/

Comment: Looks good, but two things still left:

1. If none checkbox is checked I would be able to check the whole category for car-brand or carstyle or color. Like image show I can click on Audi, Bmw and Volvo, and then filter with color and carstyle.

2. Some bug I notice when I check some checkbox and then uncheck them all, some checkboxes are still disabled.

Thx for help!

Comment: Glad to help, yes it's a rough code with the pointers on inspecting the classes to get you started - particularly on accessing the className which form your code heavily relies on it, eventually you could expand it to reset the check boxes, or even initially disable or hide the rest of the check boxes making the first step be the brand selection.

Comment: Can you fix the bug you left, if I check some checkboxes and then Uncheck them, some checkboxes is still disabled and its feels buggy. :/

Comment: Bugg: If I start to click "WHITE", I can only choose "BMW", but cant choose "VOLVO" that has white too.

Comment: Hmm your use case changed. In your question the first item you always click is the brand for example (Volvo), that is why the code was meant to check for the brand first. If you are suddenly changing the use case to start with selecting a color first then, it will change the code entirely. Here's an enhancement to the earlier fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ppzwmvs9/7/

Comment: Each category shall no filter with itselfs,  Categorys shall only filter with other Categorys .......................... Maybe this image explain it better: http://imgur.com/QJJ066l

Answer (score 0):

How to show content of checked filter that only has exacly same attribute for each category?

see also image for explanation:

[image: How to show content of checked filter that only has exacly same attribute for each category? see also image:]

.

JSFIDDLE HERE: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ar3PY/104

.

```
var getFilter = function (category) {
    var filter = $("#filters ." + category + ":checked").map(function () {
        return '[data-filter*="' + this.value + '"]';
    }).get().join(",");
    filter = (filter.length > 0) ? filter : "*";
    return filter;
}
```